# Scroll between divs - jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, web

I am working on new website, all in one page.

Now I have the main div that called "home", and the another page's divs that are called "colordiv".
now i am trying to switch between the divs by scrolling up and down.
this is my html:

```
    <div id="home" class="home_div">
         //here home page code
    </div>

    <div id="color1" class="color_div" style="background-color:#253412;">

    </div>

    <div id="color2" class="color_div" style="background-color:#956341;">

    </div>
```

and that is my jQuery code:

```
$("document").ready(function() {

    $('#learnMbtn').click(function(){

        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#color1").offset().top
        }, 600);

    });

    var lastScroll = 0;
    var temp = $("div.color_div");
    $(window).scroll(function(event){

        //Sets the current scroll position
        var st = $(this).scrollTop();

        //Determines up-or-down scrolling
        if (st > lastScroll){
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: temp.offset().top
            }, 600);
            temp = temp.next();
        }
        else {

        //here the scroll up code(prev)  

        }

        //Updates scroll position
        lastScroll = st;
    });

});
```

and this does not work for me, and I have no idea how to do the scroll up code, can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

`var temp = $("div.color_div");` this means the temp variable get a series of Elements which classname has `color_div`.

So, you use `temp.offset().top` below, jQuery don't get the current `offset().top`.

If the `.color_div` has id like `#color1 #color2 or #colorN`, maybe you can use the last number as counter and identity, like :

```
var counter = 1;
var temp = $("#color"+counter);
$(window).scroll(function(event){

    if (st > lastScroll){
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: temp.offset().top
        }, 600);
        counter++;
        temp = $("#color"+counter);
    }
    else {

        counter--;
        temp = $("#color"+counter);

    }

});
```

Comment: thank for answer, but it skips to the last div on the first time, one scroll down and it goes to downest div.

Comment: Maybe you can make a demo on JSFiddle, my answer is just a idea that could be adjust to your code, if you have more detail demo, maybe I can give you the true code.